# How to create TV Guide View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-tablelayout, android-tv

I'm building an Android app, which will display TV channels schedule.

The view would go something like, the tv guide we view on Tata sky, dish tv or any other service provider, like below:

1. Table with channel names.
2. Channel program names in a row, with time defined above, as column header..

Any idea, on how to start with creating this view in Android?
This would be like table with nequal cell widths, connected with time slots above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: recyclerview with grid

Comment: I also need to associate this with the time slots above. Like a show is scheduled for 4:00-4:30 PM, it should take only that space, and be associated with the value above. How will that be connected?

Comment: And all the items are not equal in width.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to create a custom view that would represent each cell in the TV guide. The cells would need to be defined as focusable and selectable. You would need to decide how many pixels would represent a minute. Say 4 pixels per minute. You'd then calculate a layout width based on (4px per minute x runtime in minutes). Each cell could be added to a linear layout that represents the row. Your 'grid' would be a collection of these horizontal rows.

One caveat about this method is memory usage, you wouldn't have the automatic view recycling that you get in RecyclerView so would need to take care of that manually.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! Right, need to take care of recycling views.